# Generate a result that contains multiple values from one column by WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm inexperienced with SQL, so my wording may be totally wrong. If someone could rephrase my question, I assume it'll be easy to google. Using Ms-SQL Server 2008.

I have a table where I log imports with the following columns:

```
importId
date
filename
```

In my other tables, I import three different tables per day. These can be identified by filename (such as contracts_20170105.csv, accounts_20170105.csv, ...), and I have exactly one file of each type per day.

My desired result looks like this:

```
date importId_contracts importId_accounts
```

I can identify each one individually by using

```
SELECT
    importId
FROM
    imports
WHERE
    CONVERT(DATE, date) = '2017-01-05' AND
    SUBSTRING(import.filename, 1, 5) = 'Accou'
```

but I don't know how to combine the result into the aforementioned form.

How would this be called in SQL 'slang'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work if you have only 1 file per type each day:

```
select date, 
       max(case when filename like 'contracts%' then importId end) as importId_contracts
       max(case when filename like 'accounts%' then importId end) as importId_accounts 
from Imports
where date = '2017-01-05'
group by date
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! Is there a specific name for that/similar techniques?

Comment: That is called `conditional aggregation`